# Photo gallery user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create something that is very reusable here so that I can use it in other sites for other pages etc.

This code is for a simple photo gallery,

I took the code from [here](http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-create-simple-image-gallery-using-repeater-control-jquery.html), but I changed it a bit and would like to add more functionality to it eventually, though.

#### PhotoGallery.ascx

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PhotoGallery.ascx.cs" Inherits="PhotoGallery" %>
<style>
    #ImageGallery {
        overflow:auto; 
        height:500px; 
        width:330px; 
        display:block;
    }
    #GalleryContainer {
        width:300px;
        align-content:center;
        border-right:3px solid #EEEEEE;
    }
    .thumbnails {
        cursor:pointer;
        width:100px;
    }
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ImageGallery img').click(function () {
            var bigImagePath = $(this).attr('src');
            $('#bigImage').attr('src', bigImagePath);
        });
    });
</script>
<h3>Before and After Pictures</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="GalleryContainer">
            <div id="ImageGallery">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img class="thumbnails" src='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>' alt='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img id="bigImage" alt="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### PhotoGallery.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class PhotoGallery : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateImages();
        }
    }

    public string FolderPath {get;set;}

    private void PopulateImages()
    {
        List<Image> myImages = new List<Image>();
        DirectoryInfo DI = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(FolderPath));
        foreach (var file in DI.GetFiles())
        {
            myImages.Add(new Image { ImageUrl = FolderPath + file.Name });
        }
        Repeater1.DataSource = myImages;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: You would like to add more functionality,  how does that relate to CodeReview?

Comment: If the code is not maintainable it is usually not extendable either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- the variable holding the `DirectoryInfo` object should be named using lower case.
- you should always use `Sytem.IO.Path.Combine()` to combine a folder with a filename.
- you could use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` combined with the `Select()` and assign the returned `IEnumerable` to the `DataSource` property of the `Repeater` control.
- you should add spacing to the property `FolderPath`. Instead of

  ```
  public string FolderPath {get;set;}
  ```

  you should use

  ```
  public string FolderPath { get; set; }
  ```
- `Repeater1` is an ugly name which isn't decsriptive either. Change it to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

You really just need an IEnumerable of strings and not images. You could probably directly bind the results of the GetFiles method!!

Also I don't really see a need to break the method out of Page_Load. Too many submethods leads to spaghetti.

Generally when dealing with IEnumerables there is no need to new up a list and add to it, just call a linq method on the IEnumerable you want to transform.

Comment: I disagree. I think that having the method do all the work is the right thing to do here. `Page_Load` is like `Main` it should only have the logic it absolutely needs, so we separate out the logic into methods that do certain things. like the `PopulateImages` method

Comment: For what the code is right now, I think it's overkill to apply that kind of rule, especially because it is a void method that changes the page's state which can become a big maintenance headache. If OP had a static pure method to gen the collection I would support that. I also could support the method as-is if it was being called more than once.

Comment: how does it change the page state?  it's called only on the initial page load. Are you saying that the `PopulateImages` method needs to be static?

Comment: It calls DataBind. Especially if the page becomes more complex with more methods and databound controls, a buried DataBind in a method can easily become problematic. As for the static method, no, I'm not suggesting PopulateImages be static, it can't be because it has control references. I'm suggesting a pure method that takes in the results of GetFiles and returns an IEnumerable of images (though in this case there's no need as OP doesn't need to generate any images). That kind of method can be unit tested directly and if needed broken out into a layer without having to extract UI references.

Comment: "Too many submethods leads to spaghetti." Really? I just can't get on board with that.

Comment: You should, because if the alternative is that you have a giant method, your method is doing way too much, Page_Load included. If you have a ton of logic, then it needs to go into a different object, not a different area of the same object. By the way I gave an example of an acceptable method. Back to Page_Load. It's an event on a form, not an entry point. Methods referenced in events should generally not have side effects. You could end up having issues where the method has to be called at a specific time or not be able to be called by other events, defeating the purpose of the method.

Comment: What giant method @moarboilerplate? The code here is a few lines long and I certainly wouldn't *want* to inline a ton of code into an event method. You have a fair point about a method needing to be called only at certain times, but I'm not certain that applies to this code.

Comment: That's kind of my point. If the code here is a few lines long, then keep it in Page_Load. If it's cluttering up Page_Load, then components of it need to be broken up in an object-oriented fashion like I described, not by wholesale copying the code into a void method. There's a vast difference between a method that is being treated like a method on an object, and a method that is being treated like a procedural subroutine. At the end of the day, when you write methods that are subroutines, you risk future headaches.